# Retrieve private methods of objects from localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, object, local-storage

I have defined a factory function to generate objects of a certain "class":

```
const myObject = function(param) {

  const attribute = param;

  const _privateMethod = function {};

  const publicMethod = function {};

  return {attribute, publicMethod,};

};

const instance = myObject(arg)
```

And I'm saving this object to localStorage:

```
const jsonString = JSON.stringify(instance);

window.localStorage.setItem("object", jsonString);
```

When I recover the objects the methods aren't there of course, so I reassociate the methods to the objects like this:

```
const rJsonString = window.localStorage.getItem("object");

const rInstance = JSON.parse(rJsonString);

const {publicMethod,} = myObject(rInstance.attribute);

Object.assign(rInstance, {publicMethod,});
```

Is there a way to reassociate the private methods?

Comment: Those aren't private methods. They're local variables holding functions.

Comment: I should reinstantiate the objects shouldn't I? I just thought of that...

Comment: @CollinD Do you think I should use the class keyword instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "better" approach, in objective terms?

Comment: @TylerH I meant a substitution of whatever constructs I'm using to achieve the same end... e.g. using constructors instead of factory functions or simply the way you do it, I might find it more suitable.

Comment: @R.Alberto I don't see how that describes something "better", only something "different".

Comment: @TylerH I do not _know_ if there is a better approach or not, that's why this is a _question_. It's unambiguous, someone might see the question and think "Well you're making it difficult yourself, here try this instead." I really don't see what you want.

Comment: @R.Alberto I _want_ you to avoid opinion-based language, because that's not the kind of thing that belongs on Stack Overflow. I'm trying to find out what it is you really _mean_ by "better", since that's vague and in the eye of the beholder. When someone asks for how to write some piece of code "better", they could mean the number of lines of code, they could refer to some principle like DRY, they could be thinking of some coding style guide (like Python's PEP guides), etc. But unless they specify what they mean, readers/answerers are left to guess at what OP is _really_ asking for.

Comment: Everyone always wants their code to be the "best" it can be. People generally don't take the time to write up answers with suboptimal solutions if they know there is something better they could provide, instead. In rare cases, they do know, but still end up providing the suboptimal solution _for a reason_, and they _give_ that reason. You should always assume people will give you the 'best' answer, and don't waste time asking for. Instead, spend your time and words asking for specifically what you want, so that _everyone_ who reads your question knows for sure what a good or right answer is.

Comment: In this case, you ask for something "better". What is it about your code, specifically, that makes you think it could be written "better"? What does "better" mean? How could a machine compare other code with yours and come to the conclusion that the other code is "better" than yours? In this case you're having to reassociate methods with objects after retrieval... ostensibly you should be asking "How can I generate and store objects in localStorage without disassociating their private methods?" or something similar instead of "how can I do this better?".

Comment: I know there is no way to way to store objects in localStorage without dissociating methods. In my question my purpose is clear. By better I mean if some more experienced user finds their approach to be better (clearer, faster, less verbose) in some way than mine. I said better because I'm open to consider different approaches and I can decide if one fits better for my purposes. On the other hand, my intent is very clear and specific... So what is wrong with the subjectivity of a better approach, if what I want is people exposing diverse points of view?

Comment: By the way, your edit changed my intent, because I'm thinking there could exist an altogether different approach to achieve the same end...

Comment: [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) is for **data serialization** which covers a small subset of available JS types. Unless the OP provides a custom [`replacer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#parameters) function as 2nd parameter, or even better, implements an object's own [`toJSON`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#description) method, the serialization of types as used by the OP fails.

Comment: And because of all of that, every suitable approach always will be based on saving an object's / instance's state in a JSON conform way from which such a type can be easily re-created again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I would do this would be to either:

1. Create a class for these objects, and add a method to instantiate from a plain js object (this is what you'll get back from JSON.parse)

```
class MyObject {
  constructor(plainMyObject) {
    // or whatever
    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(plainMyObject)) {
      this[key] = value;
    }
  }

  publicMethod() {
    this._privateMethod();
    // or
    this.#privateMethod();
  }

  _privateMethod() {
    // . . .
  }

  // or using real private methods
  #privateMethod() {
  // ...
  }
}

const obj = new MyObject(JSON.parse(localStorageStringValue));
obj.publicMethod();
```

2. Just create functions that can be used to manage your objects, keeping them as plain objects

```
export function publicMethod(obj) {
  privateFunction(obj);
}

function privateFunction(obj) {
  // ...
}

publicMethod(JSON.parse(localStorageStringValue));
```

These approaches are fairly equivalent. Classes obviously allow for polymorphism and inheritance, while the function-based/imperative approach does not. Often you don't need these things, and just having a small library of related functions is simpler and more performant than classes.

Comment: Thank you for your time. The course I'm taking discourages the use of classes, that's why I got into this mess apparently. I actually managed to do it by reinstantiating all the objects, but I had to tweak them a little so all constructor attributes would be accessible. Still seeing your point of view is very valuable as I'm learning this weird language.